# Is a block in Objective-C always guaranteed to capture a variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, objective-c++

Are there any conditions in Objective-C (Objective-C++) where the compiler can detect that a variable capture in a block is never used and thus decide to not capture the variable in the first place?

For example, assume you have an `NSArray` that contains a large number of items which might take a long time to deallocate. You need to access the `NSArray` on the main thread, but once you're done with it, you're willing to deallocate it on a background queue. The background block only needs to capture the array and then immediately deallocate. It doesn't actually have to do anything with it. Can the compiler detect this and, "erroneously", skip the block capture altogether?

Example:

```
// On the main thread...
NSArray *outgoingRecords = self.records;
self.records = incomingRecords;

dispatch_async(background_queue, ^{
  (void)outgoingRecords;

  // After this do-nothing block exits, then outgoingRecords
  // should be deallocated on this background_queue.  
});
```

Am I guaranteed that `outgoingRecords` will always be captured in that block and that it will always be deallocated on the `background_queue`?

**Edit #1**

I'll add a bit more context to better illustrate my issue:

I have an Objective-C++ class that contains a very large std::vector of immutable records. This could easily be 1+ million records. They are basic structs in a vector and accessed on the main thread to populate a table view. On a background thread, a different set of database records might be read into a separate vector, which could also be quite large.

Once the background read has occurred, I jump over to the main thread to swap Objective-C objects and repopulate the table.

At that point, I don't care at all about the contents of the older vector or its parent Objective-C class. There's no fancy destructors or object-graph to teardown, but deallocating hundreds of megabytes, maybe even gigabytes of memory is not instantaneous. So I'm willing to punt it off to a background_queue and have the memory deallocation occur there. In my tests, that appears to work fine and gives me a little bit more time on the main thread to do other stuff before 16ms elapses.

I'm trying to understand if I can get away with simply capturing the object in an "empty" block or if I should do some sort of no-op operation (like call `count`) so that the compiler cannot optimize it away somehow.

**Edit #2**

*(I originally tried to keep the question as simple as possible, but it seems like it's more nuanced then that. Based on Ken's answer below, I'll add another scenario.)*

Here's another scenario that doesn't use dispatch_queues but still uses blocks, which is the part I'm really interested in.

```
id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = ...

// A custom class that manages an MTLTexture that is backed by an IOSurface.
__block MyTextureWrapper *wrapper = ... 

// Issue some Metal calls that use the texture inside the wrapper.

// Wait for the buffer to complete, then release the wrapper.
[commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> cb) {
  wrapper = nil;
}];
```

In this scenario, the order of execution is guaranteed by Metal. Unlike the example above, in this scenario performance is not the issue. Rather, the IOSurface that is backing the `MTLTexture` is being recycled into a CVPixelBufferPool. The IOSurface is being shared between processes and, from what I can tell, `MTLTexture` does not appear to increase the useCount on the surface. My wrapper class does. When my wrapper class is deallocated, the useCount is decremented and the bufferPool is then free to recycling the IOSurface.

This is all working as expected but I end up with silly code like above just out of uncertainty whether I need to "use" the wrapper instance in the block to ensure it's captured or not. If the wrapper is deallocated before the completion handler runs, then the IOSurface will be recycled and the texture will get overwritten.

Comment: If the reference is not used, why it matters that it would be deallocated sooner?

Comment: If deallocating that array takes a long time, then I would prefer it be done on a background queue rather than on the main queue, where it would block the user interface.

Comment: I am not really sure what would take so much time during deallocation but in similar situations I would assume that allocation takes much more time. Have you thought about reusing the objects?

Comment: The array deallocation takes no time.   It is the contents that may be problematic.   And if they are, then the costly part of deallocation needs to be separated from the actual call to `dealloc`.   In fact, if there is any kind of communication outside of the object during deallocation, then you really need to move that logic out of deallocation where the object graph is in a known inconsistent state.

Comment: So you're question regarding Edit 2 is whether you could get away with `(void)wrapper` instead of declaring `wrapper` with `__block` and clearing it in the block? It would certainly be safe to do `[wrapper self]`, but that's not much less "silly" but avoids `__block`.

Comment: From a personal coding guideline, I try and minimize the use of `__block`. It's not a big deal, but something that led me to wanting to better understand how a block captures variables and whether it's allowed to not capture them in certain conditions. Your quote of the spec below clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit to address question edits:

From the Clang [Language Specification for Blocks](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html):

> Local automatic (stack) variables referenced within the compound
>   statement of a Block are imported and captured by the Block as const
>   copies. The capture (binding) is performed at the time of the Block
>   literal expression evaluation.
>
> The compiler is not required to capture a variable if it can prove
>   that no references to the variable will actually be evaluated.
>   **Programmers can force a variable to be captured by referencing it in a
>   statement at the beginning of the Block, like so**:
>
> ```
> (void) foo;
> ```
>
> **This matters when capturing the variable has side-effects, as it can
>   in Objective-C or C++**.

(Emphasis added.)

Note that using this technique guarantees that the referenced object lives at least as long as the block, but does not guarantee it will be released with the block, nor by which thread.

---

There's no guarantee that the block submitted to the background queue will be the last code to hold a strong reference to the array (even ignoring the question of whether the block captures the variable).

First, the block may in fact run before the context which submitted it returns and releases its strong reference. That is, the code which called `dispatch_async()` could be swapped off the CPU and the block could run first.

But even if the block runs somewhat later than that, a reference to the array may be in an autorelease pool somewhere and not released for some time. Or there may be a strong reference someplace else that will eventually be cleared but not under you explicit control.

Comment: Good points Ken, thank you. I've added a second example to the original question that does away with GCD and execution order because that's not entirely what I was concerned about, though it is a very valid point I hadn't fully considered in the case of deallocating a large vector.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for yet failed to find on my own. Unsurprisingly it's right there in the docs. This was as much about personal knowledge regarding block semantics as it was anything else but does "save me" from having to use the `__block` attribute and allows me to remove the `= nil` code, which I've preferred to do since ARC was introduced.